# Add notification bar at the top of the page

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a notification bar at the top of the page using `ngx-notification-bar` module.

I followed the same steps as mentioned in this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-notification-bar)

`app.module.ts` file contains below part of code

```
import { NotificationBarModule } from 'ngx-notification-bar'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
      NotificationBarModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

`app.component.ts` file contains this

```
import { NotificationBarService } from 'ngx-notification-bar';

constructor(private notificationBarService:NotificationBarService){

this.notificationBarService.create({ message: 'USER_SAVED', type: NotificationType.Success});
}
```

And `app.component.html` contains this

```
<notification-bar></notification-bar>
```

But I am not able to add a notification bar at the top of the page. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe try to call ```this.notificationBarService.create``` in ngOnInit instead of directly in the constructor?

Comment: @Lukasz Gawrys yes, by making this change I am able to see the notification bar, but only for a fraction of a second. Is there a way to make it static (so that it does not disappear) ?

Comment: According to the docs you can pass another param autoHide: false to the create function and then it should not disappear.